# Is trustless BTC-LTC-ETH peg possible with Segwit?

Tags: ether, bitcoin, sidechain

I thought there were some discussions in 2016 that a trustless peg was possible between ETH and BTC. (Probably related to rootstock). With segwit in place, can this be done now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic is still in discussion, but I don't think segwit change the situation. Tt depends on what you mean with *trustless* but if you mean **provably** and **without intermediaries**, technically it can be done with many blockchains and it is actually done between Bitcoin and Ethereum; the most famous - and the only one I know being *in production* - is [BTC Relay](http://btcrelay.org/).

Still, every solution in this moment has its own pros and cons.

Comment: And even BTC Relay is only one way from BTC to Ethereum network.